# WYSIWYG HTML editing for a whole document?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm currently facing a situation where I get a whole HTML document as part of a JSON object and would like to let the user edit it in a WYSIWG fashion. My current approach is to use TinyMCE but I'd be open for other suggestion as well.

The problem I'm facing using TinyMCE is that that part of the document is being lost if a user edits it. Would anyone know a solution to work around this?

The below example contains a string with a simple HTML document that is being displayed within the `textarea`. After the documents loads, you will see that the area contains the whole document. If you continue to click on the "Init" button, it will initialize TinyMCE and you will find that the markup is being read and that you can even change it. The problem is that, regardless of whenever you press save or view the source using the options in "tools", only the `body` part of the document remains.

The document is actually a out of office message from exchange. The original code is a bit more complex but this is a minimal working example I came up with.

So would anyone happen to know how I could enable a user to still be able to do some formatting in a WYSIWG fashion while also preserving the original HTML markup that is being loaded? That primarily means including the `html`, `head` etc. tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea', plugins:'code' })">Init</button>
    <button onclick="tinyMCE.editors[0].save()">Save</button>
    <button onclick="tinyMCE.editors[0].remove()">Remove</button><br />
    <textarea id="editorArea" style="width: 100%;" rows="15"></textarea>
    <script>
    var htmlElements = `
        <html xmlns:o="urn:schema-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <head>
            <style>
                body{font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 55pt;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 7pt">Here is some text.</span>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>`;
    document.getElementById("editorArea").innerHTML = htmlElements;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want users to be able to edit the head and body content, or just the body? 'Cause you could always just extract the body, put it in a WYSIWYG editor and then wrap it back with the rest of the HTML.

Comment: With the case at hand it could be a bit difficult. The problem is that the out of office message contains specific office HTML code. That way I'd have to first extract the body (using another approach as the head for each message might be different) and glue them together later on. Meanwhile the styles etc. that are contained in the head might be important for some advanced users. It's a pretty silly thing I need to do. The solution was/is to use the `fullpage` plugin which easily enables an advance view for advanced users and everyone else just sees the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fullpage` plugins allows someone to work with the entire HTML document when looking at the code view of the content:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/fullpage/

When you then save the content you should get back the entire document.

Comment: I actually stumbled across that a bit later one but didn't write an answer myself. It's really working like a charm (so far).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is the best approach or not. But this is what i did in one of my project. My use case was to render markdown text or html on browser and it should be editable. I used [showdown.js](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) in this case, you are free to choose any library.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.6.4/showdown.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <br />
  <div id="editorArea" contentEditable="true" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  <script>
    var htmlElements = `<html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body{font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 55pt;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 7pt; color: #dd0000;">Here is some editable text.</span>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>`;
    var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
    text      = htmlElements,
    output      = converter.makeHtml(text);
    document.getElementById("editorArea").innerHTML = output;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea but doesn't really solve my problem as I already have HTML that a user should edit. With this approach I would first need to convert HTML to Markdown and later on into HTML again to make it editable. But in some other cases this might be interesting.

Comment: No you don't need to convert html to markdown, this library understands both html & markdown.  In my example i gave html as an input not markdown.